# fgets не считывает текстовые данные из файла

Tags: c

Пытаюсь считать данные из файла с помощью функции fgets:

```
FILE* txtfile = fopen(txtfile_name, "r");
    if (txtfile == NULL)
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    int64_t size = file_size(txtfile);
    char* arr = (char*)malloc(size);
    fgets(arr, size, txtfile);
```

Функция file_size просто определяет размер файла в байтах, fgets возвращает NULL, из-за чего это может происходить?
Спасибо!

Comment: Наверное, ваша `file_size` **так** определяет размер, что выставляет указатель на конец файла - вот ничего и не читается...

Comment: @Harry, да, я ставлю указатель на конец файла, в этом проблема, совершенно забыл, что нужно вернуть.. Спасибо!

Comment: @Harry, опять ответы в комментариях...

Comment: @Qwertiy Да ну не тянет оно на ответ: нет полной информации, так, из опыта - просто догадка :) Более того - вопрос на закрытие, как вызванный опиской...

Comment: @Harry, ничего не опиской. Нормальный вопрос и нормальный ответ)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вероятно, написанная вами функция `file_size` основана на смещении указателя на конец файла и получении его позиции, но обратного смещения в позицию, в которой он был до вызова (не обязательно в начальную, заметим) не происходит.

Соответственно, чтение из файла оказывается невозможным.